# Android Activity onInitialize

Tags: android, oncreate, livecycle

I would like to do some action only once, when the app starts.
Therefore, I tried to place the code within the main acitivity's onCreate, but this is triggered again and again when the user comes back to the main activity and/or when the device orientation changes.
Which event fits better for my use-case?

Comment: onCreate should only be called when the Activity is recreated. If you launch your app, press home, and launch your app again it would only call onResume

Comment: consider storing a boolean in sharedpreferences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

write the code in application level.

```
Class MyClass extends Application
   {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
           //your code. This will be executed only once.i.e. when app is started.

           super.onCreate();
     }
   }
```

You need to declare this class in androidmanifest.xml also .As shown

```
<application
    android:name=".MyClass"
    android:icon="@drawable/logo"
    android:label="@string/str_app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" 
    >
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a static boolean, and check if this boolean is already set or not

for e.g

```
private static boolean flag = false;
  // perform this check inside oncreate
    if(!flag){
      // peform task
       flag = true;
    }
```

This will make your code run only once, when the program starts.